# How to clone a packet and change Ethernet, IP, and UDP header fields in DPDK?

Tags: clone, dpdk

I am trying to clone the packet and change various layer 2/3/4 header fields in the cloned packets.

Based on the examples gives in the DPDK repository and over the internet, rte_pktmbuf_prepend() has been used in almost all the examples. After prepending the required header, those newly added headers are changed to reflect the newer value of various fields. As far as I understand, **rte_pktmbuf_clone()** will clone all the segments and **why can't we change the header fields in the cloned packets and why do we need to prepend the headers after cloning the packet?**

Moreover, in ipv4_multicast(DPDK example application), the headers are being removed first using **rte_pktmbuf_adj()** and then new headers are prepended to the packet. **So, in some examples, headers are removed first and then new headers are added and in some other examples, the new headers are added. Why do we need to do this?**

Thanks.

Related links:

http://dpdk.org/ml/archives/dev/2014-March/001589.html

http://dpdk.org/ml/archives/dev/2014-March/001583.html

http://dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/v17.08/sample_app_ug/ipv4_multicast.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DPDK (as in many other libraries), the idea behind mbufs is to split data (i.e. Ethernet frame with IP packet inside) and metadata (i.e. number of buffers in chain, pointer to a next buffer, flags, total length etc).

The `rte_pktmbuf_clone()` for a given mbuf allocates another metadata. This metadata get attached to the original mbuf data, i.e. the original and cloned mbufs share the same data after the cloning, but have two separate metadata. This is described in more details in [Programer's Guide.](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/prog_guide/mbuf_lib.html#direct-and-indirect-buffers)

Now answering your question.

> why can't we change the header fields in the cloned packets and why do we need to prepend the headers after cloning the packet?

In fact, we CAN change packet headers in the cloned packets, but since (after the cloning) two mbufs share the same buffer data, changing data one mbuf will change data in another, since the mbuf data is shared.

The goal of some examples to send the same mbuf to N destinations simultaneously. The simplest solution would be to:

1. Allocate N new mbufs.
2. Make N copies of original data.
3. Change packet headers N times for N destinations.
4. Send those mbufs to N different interfaces.

Unfortunately, making N copies of data just to change few bytes at the beginning is not the most efficient solution. So instead we clone the packets, i.e.:

1. Allocate N new mbufs metadata (i.e. much less then previously).
2. Attach N mbufs to the original data (i.e. no data copy).

Now, since all N mbufs share the same data, we cannot change packet headers for N different destinations. So, instead we allocate another mbuf just for packet headers, i.e.:

3. Allocate N mbufs for packet headers.
4. Fill packet headers N times for N destinations.
5. Prepend N headers to the N cloned mbufs.
6. Send those mbufs to N different interfaces.

So, the process is more complicated than previously, but potentially could show better performance, because we never copy the packet data, which might be up to ~65K in some cases.

> So, in some examples, headers are removed first and then new headers are added and in some other examples, the new headers are added. Why do we need to do this?

It depends if need just to change packet headers and send it out or we need to make N copies with N different packet headers as described above. Overall, DPDK is very performance focused, so we can take for granted, that all those complications there is for a reason...